# How to Host app send data to app extension in IOS action extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

i have done sample action extension app. am not able to get host app request data.i think is there some issue with this code.

Host App request code

```
  NSDictionary *request = @{@"username”:@“username”,@“password”:@“password”};
            UIActivityViewController *extensionController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[request] applicationActivities:nil];
           extensionController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        [self presentViewController:extensionController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

App Extension code

```
NSExtensionItem *inputItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems[0];

    NSItemProvider *itemprovider = inputItem.attachments[0];

    [itemprovider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList options:nil completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *results = (NSDictionary *)item;

        NSLog(@“Host app Request Data=%@",results);

    }];
```

am not sure what's wrong above code, can anyone help me.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turn on **App Groups** and use **NSUserDefaults**

1. Turn on App Groups and add group name in your both host target and extension target Capabilities
2. Input set data in host app source

```
    //use our group user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]  
    initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.organization.ProductName"];

    //set a greeting
    [defaults setObject:@"username" forKey:@"username"];
    [defaults setObject:@"password" forKey:@"password"];

    //synchronise
    [defaults synchronize];
```

3. SomeExtension.m

```
    //use our group user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] 
    initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.organization.ProductName"];

    //get the greeting    
    NSString *username = [defaults stringForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *password = [defaults stringForKey:@"password"];

    //check if greeting isn't empty
    NSLog(@"username = %@ / password = %@", username, password);
```

Comment: Do not provide link only answers as links may expire in future.Try to quote some relevant code or some part of the code that is useful in answering ques.

Comment: Never share any passwords or other sensible data in the `NSUserDefaults`. Use the [Keychain Services API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) instead, which will encrypt it properly.